# Receiving strange output using SerialPort for a Toledo module (scale device)

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, scale

I'm currently working with a client, and have been requested to accommodate some intake of a legacy Toledo module from the early '80s. The manual I was given by the technicians was for a 8530 DigiTOL INDICATOR

The process is through serial and I'm using .Net [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Everything seems to be going well. But the output is of something I can't recognize. I can't seem to achieve any successful encoding of the output nor is the manual of use.

I've updated a bit, perhaps and hopefully in the correct direction. However the output is still garbage.

Code:

```
public static void Open(String portName)
{
    try
    {
        serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
        {
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true,
            Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591),
        };

        serialPort.DataReceived += serialPort_OnDataReceived;
        serialPort.ErrorReceived += serialPort_ErrorReceived;

        shutdown = false;

        serialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Connection open on {0}", portName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection failed on {0}. {1}", portName, ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void serialPort_OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data received...");

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        Encoding encoder = Encoding.Default;

        while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0 || shutdown)
        {
            b.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", serialPort.ReadByte());
            b.AppendFormat(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not read data from port {0}. {1}", serialPort.PortName, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However as stated, this is still outputting untranslatable data.

Example of output (Hex)

Connection open on COM1

82 3e 14 16 
0b c1 b0 58 58 2c 16 16
0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 58 2c 16 16 
0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35 
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58 
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35
82 3e 14 16 0b c1 b0 58
58 2c 16 16 0b 0b 35

Connection closed on COM1

This translates to:

> Á ° X X ,
>     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X X ,
>     5 
>      Á ° X
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5 
>      Á ° X 
>   X ,     5
>      Á ° X
>   X ,     5
>      Á ° X
>   X ,     5

Here is a screenshot of the output PuTTY displays w/ same baud rate, parity, data and stop bit
http://i58.tinypic.com/mj9yk3.png

UPDATE

So I have spoken with the technicians. I am receiving errors. Since I could not make sense of it before, and at the time overlooked it. **I receive a Frame error every other message received.** From looking around I see this could mean a few things. Baud rate mismatches, serial line is too long or there's a lot of electrical noise on the serial cable. I can confirm my software, windows and the module all have the same setup which is Baud rate 9600, Data bits 8, Parity none and Stop bits 1. I can also confirm the manual for this confirms this is a valid setup.

Comment: Are you sure the serial port settings (baud rate, etc) are correct? Usually gibberish means you've got a setting wrong. Check the manual if it's available.

Comment: Yes I was just there with the technicians and their settings matched that of mine. Could it be that we've set (matched) settings not fully supported by this particular model. I would question why it has the available options if it didn't though.

Comment: Bummer, there go my points. Why the downvotes? Help me improve or remain anonymous and help no body.

Comment: Downvotes aren't from me, but I'm going to guess that it's because there really isn't enough information to answer your question. Assuming that your port settings are correct, there is nothing obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: You don't list any of the Encodings you tried but for a 30 yr old piece it is going to be ASCII. If it reports in text at all. You'll really need the specs or a better tool to reverse engineer this.

Comment: Also, ReadExisitng() is probably not the right tool. There are hundreds of SerialPort Q+A's on this site, do a little research.

Comment: I have and I've tried them. For simplicity and quick implements. I have chosen ReadExisting() All other methods of reading the buffer yield identical results. I added a combo so I can real time adjust the encoding. Yes ASCII was my first choice. The text did change a little but still gibberish. I also tried Windows-1252 as some most posts demonstrated. I left those bits out on purpose as they seem to not be my issue. The techs were messing around with the serial pins on the main board. Could there be an issue there? I just don't know enough about the tech to know what to ask.

Comment: If your serial port settings are correct and the device is not outputting ASCII, there's a good chance it's using some kind of binary protocol. There's not a whole lot you can do without some tech specs on this thing. Googling the device manufacturer, model, and "serial protocol" or something like that may yield results.

Comment: Thanks @jonb, I have updated with more information. Now that I've obtained the manual I will call out and do some more research. It seems you may have pointed me in the correct direction.

Comment: You definitely need to look up the manual and see what it says. Also look to see what commands you might be able to send it. Some have commands that switch modes (for example, from a continuous mode where it streams data constantly to one where you have to request a reading). Assuming [this](http://diagramasde.com/diagramas/otros/Manual%20Tecnico%208530.pdf) is the correct manual?

Comment: @MattBurland Yes that's the correct manual, or rather the one I've been referencing. The technicians setup the module for continuous out on the supplied 25-pin serial port. We are doing direct serial to serial at the moment there is no cross-over. When we used one we would receive no data, without we received a continuous flow of garbage. Now mind you my readings match what PuTTY displays with the same settings (see update).

Comment: Chapter 6 of that manual has the information you need to understand the scale's protocol. You'll have to spend some quality time going over that. Look at the hex data you've captured, and try to make sense of it based on the manual. Then you'll be able to write code to parse it out and use it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Technicians figured it out! The manual we had was not the original, perhaps not even for our exact model. Regardless, it had suggested to me a baud rate of 9600, data bits of 8, no parity and 1 stop bit was a valid configuration and should work. This was wrong for our device model and apparently not supported (though the device was set and seemed to support a 9600 baud rate -- options were available in setup mode).

**It appears the correct configuration is baud rate of 4800, 7 data bits no parity and 1 stop bit.**

With this it worked beautifully and I get the data I'm looking for! :)

Thanks everyone.